# Accessing firestore inside createUserWithEmailAndPassword method

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

i'm building the app using expo / react native and the firebase javascript web sdk. Could someone take a look at the code below and let me know whether they can figure out why my code isn't working? The code works fine when I'm using expo development mode, and the user profile gets set as expected. However in it's published state it is just not working. The new user is created and logged in, however it doesn't create the user profile.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
.catch(() => {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((newUser) => {
        var userRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(newUser.uid);
        userRef.set({name: name, email: email, company: company, number: number, user: newUser.uid, adminEmail: '' })
        .then(function (){
          dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: newUser });
        })
        .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch)
        );
    })
    .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
```

I've tried lots of different methods but keep having the same problem. According to the docs, the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method returns the User credentials. I've confirmed this with a debug statement and checked that I am accessing the uid property of said object. 
Thanks

Comment: Just a follow up. The app seems to running fine in iOS but not in android. However it does work on android in expo development mode. Firebase firestore  does work on android once the user is inside the app though